# How to make a wavy effect in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the game Super Luigi Galaxy, when the player falls into cold water, the screen waves. Is there a possible way to do this effect in Unity?

The effect looks like this: https://youtu.be/uj3TWvUlLqs?t=4m19s

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irzkz.png

I do not know the name of this effect, sorry for my lack of details.

Comment: Post processing shaders.

Comment: Yes, as @Draco18s said, you can find more in the asset store. [Here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/83912) is a free one from Unity. It has more than few effects like blur, gloom, color correction etc.

Comment: @EmreE I installed the Post Processing Stack, but none of the effects are what I want.

Comment: You could try to tweak few of them, might get you the effect you want not sure. There are also paid assets, maybe they have the effect you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for being stupid.

1) Add a new shader, material, and C# script

2) The scripting. 
Shader (add to bottom, and remove the color inversion):

```
        uniform float _waveLength;
        uniform float _waveNumber;

        fixed4 frag (v2f IN) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv + float2(sin(IN.vertex.y / _waveLength + _Time[1]*50) / _waveNumber, 0));

            return col;
        }
```

C#:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class testscript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material mat;

    public float waveNumber;
    public float waveLength;

    void Update()
    {
        Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_waveLength", waveNumber); // I know I switched the variables on accident. It still works though.
        Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_waveNumber", waveLength);
    }

    void OnRenderImage( RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(src, dest, mat);
    }
}
```

3) Attach the C# script to the Camera, attach the shader to the material, and attach the material to the C# script. Add a cube to the scene to view the effect. Go to playing mode on Unity, and adjust the settings on the script.

4) What to the variables do?

a) Wave Number:
The amount of waves,
1 = a lot of waves
30 = very few waves

b) Wave Length:
How far to offset the x of the waves,
1 = VERY wide waves
1000 = VERY short waves

I recommend the wave number at 1, and the wave length at 100.

Comment: The problem here is that it shakes the sprite texture back and forth as it makes the waves (I'm going for a starry field water reflection effect) on my sprite backdrop.  Any idea how to stop that from happening? Or at least slow the wave interval?  controlling the update frequency in the Update() loop doesn't seem to do anything.